# How to count users that follow a particular sequence?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following table:

Sequence is the order in which events happen within the session_id.

1 = first, 2= second, 3 = third etc. etc. The number of events per session_id are unlimited so the sequence could go as high a 40+

I am using Snowflake warehouse for the analysis.

| cust_id | event | session_id | sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | quote_phone | 12341 | 1 |
| 1234 | quote_online | 12342 | 1 |
| 1234 | quote_online | 12342 | 2 |
| 1234 | purchase_phone | 12342 | 3 |
| 5678 | quote_online | 56781 | 1 |
| 5678 | purchase_online | 56781 | 2 |
| 7921 | quote_online | 7921 | 1 |
| 7921 | quote_phone | 7921 | 2 |
| 7921 | quote_phone | 7921 | 3 |
| 7921 | purchase_phone | 7921 | 4 |
| 7921 | quote_online | 7921 | 5 |

Output I would like to see is

segment1 = where session_id had a quote_phone only 
segment2 = where session_id started (sequence = 1) with a quote_online and then purchase_phone (sequence =2 ) 
segment3 =  where session_id started with quote_online and then purchase_online
segment4 = where session_id started with quote_online, then quote_phone then purchase_phone

| cust_id | session_id | segment1 | segment2 | segment3 | segment4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 12341 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1234 | 12342 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5678 | 56781 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 7921 | 79211 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: These segments are not mutually exclusive.  Please provide more explanation.

Comment: Hi Gordon - thanks for your comments. Updated the segment definition to be mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly here is one way :

```
select
    cust_id,
    session_id,
    case when count(case when event = 'quote_phone' then 1 end) = count(*) 
    then 1 else 0 end as segment1
    , case when min(case when event = 'quote_online' then sequenc end) = 1
            and max(case when event = 'purchase_phone' then sequence end) = 2 
    then 1 else 0 end as segment2
    , case when min(case when event = 'quote_online' then sequence end) = 1
            and max(case when event = 'purchase_online' then sequence end) > 1 
    then 1 else 0 end as segment3
    , case when min(case when event = 'quote_online' then sequence end) = 1
            and max(case when event = 'quote_phone' then sequence end) > 1
            and max(case when event = 'purchase_online' then sequence end) 
              > max(case when event = 'purchase_phone' then sequence end) 
    then 1 else 0 end as segment4
from table
group by cust_id,session_id
```

Comment: Thank for this. When I run it I get an error though- Snowflake is throwing an error though - i it doesn't like the closed bracket on line 2  'quote_phone') or the closed bracket on line 2 - then sequence)

Comment: @NickEdwards that was an extra brackert , removed , see updated answer

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't like the closed bracket on line 3 either  - then sequence) - any ideas?

Comment: Every  `CASE WHEN...` should be ended with `END`, for instance: `min(case when event = 'quote_online' then sequence)` => `min(case when event = 'quote_online' then sequence end)`

Comment: Thank you! All sorted now.